# How to make Netbeans hotdeploys to Glassfish faster?

Tags: java, deployment, netbeans, netbeans-7, hotdeploy

On changing a single line of code or just adding a comment line, netbeans redeploys the entire project to server, which eats up lot of development/debugging time. I know, I can disable the hot deploys but I don't want that, I just want to make hot deploys work faster so that I could test changes faster on browser.
Moreover in debugging mode it is even worse in terms of time taken for deployment.

Is there something I can do about ? Or should I do hot deploys some other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know any way of doing it in Netbeans itself, but you can always take a look at [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel).

This tool monitors your class folders and hotdeploys them to the application server when a file has changed. I use this in Eclipse with Tomcat and it works very good for me.

Comment: Jrebel will only redeploy the class files you actualy changed, so the entire project won't get redeployed.

Comment: @user01 you should differentiate "hotdeploy" and "hotupdate". NetBeans itself can trigger redeploy process, meaning that a new class loader is created and all the new versions of class files and libraries are loaded again, and if you're lucky, session will be serialized/deserialized. With JRebel, it updates only the changed classes/resources without creating a new class loader thus preserving the session state. This is much more convenient approach for large apps and the speed will not be an issue.

Comment: @user935439: Thanks so much for introducing me to JRebel ! Perfectly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope this solution is working out for you :)